# Spark-shell Git Bash

Tags: java, bash, scala, apache-spark, git-bash

I cannot get the spark-shell command to work on Git bash. I am fairly sure my environment is set up correctly as if I run spark-shell in any directory in command prompt, it works just fine for me.

However, when I run spark-shell in bash, it outputs this value instead of running the actual shell:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java" -cp "C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin- 
hadoop2.7/conf\;C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\*" "- 
Dscala.usejavacp=true"-Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class 
org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" spark-shell
```

Comment: Do you mean you are running spark from within a shell script file? If so, can you show us that script? If not, how are you running it?

Comment: No, I'm just calling spark-shell without a script.
I just call spark-shell in any directory and it runs in command prompt, however, for git bash, it displays the above output.

Answer (score 0):

In a git bash, try and use:

- simple quotes `'` (instead of double-quotes `"`)
- `/` instead of `\`: `C:/.../...` or `/c/.../...`

That would be more compatible with the shell used by Git bash.

Comment: To clarify, the above is the output that I am returned, I am just calling `spark-shell`

Comment: @Foxlooo Any chance to modify the `spark-shell` script in order to test the syntax I propose?

Comment: I'm not sure what script it's running, I'm running it from the default built-in command from the installation of spark and scala.
Also, keep in mind it works in command prompt

Comment: @Foxlooo OK. I am not surprised it does work in a CMD command prompt, and not in a bash (where quotes are interpreted differently)

Answer (score 0):

Then run it as `RUN=($( spark-shell  )) && "${RUN[@]}"`